# Joins between null

Tags: date, join, null, between

```
RouteNo Date

100 24/4/2014

100 25/5/2014

100 26/6/2014

200 24/4/2014

200 

200 26/6/2014

300 24/4/2014

300 25/5/2014

300 26/6/2014
```

I want to search all the route numbers (dates between 1/5/2014 to 31/5/2014) & show me the route if that route doesn't any date in between 1/5/2014 to 31/05/2014)
In the result I need 200 because it doesn't have May date. 
Anyone please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct; 
I would think something like this might work:

```
SELECT RouteNo
FROM <your table>
WHERE RouteNo NOT IN (
    SELECT RouteNo FROM <your table> 
    WHERE [Date] >= '20140501' AND [Date] <= '20140531'
)
```

Comment: I have other joins as well                                                select utl_reader_route.reader_route_code,utl_reader_route_date.read_date
from utl_reader_route_date
join utl_reader_route
on utl_reader_route.reader_route_id=utl_reader_route_date.reader_route_id
Join utl_meter_reader
on utl_reader_route.meter_reader_id=utl_meter_reader.meter_reader_id
where utl_meter_reader.meter_reader_code='ADR MRS' and utl_reader_route_date.read_date between '2014-05-01' and '2014-05-31'
order by read_date

Comment: Well - You only showed RouteNo and Date when I wrote the answer; so there's no way anybody can know what additional things you have. Plus the NOT IN method should still work with "other joins".

Comment: Thanks Hansen, Sorry I am very new to this website & SQL. Thanks for your help

Comment: in SQL there are usually several ways to get the same result; and you should be able to do it with outer joins (left or right) and where you then add a condition in there WHERE that something must be NULL. But generally speaking it's easier to work with NOT IN in those situations unless you know what you're doing because such queries can be quite complex

Comment: Thanks Hansen, Is it possible for you help me here, I will very very thankful to you? I want to get everything from utl_reader_route, even it's doesn't have any date between 1/5/14 and 31/5/2014

Comment: If you make a question with schema, test data and restrictions and what you've tried so far etc, here on S.O. - more people will be able to help.

Comment: I have done this as per your instruction, could you please help now?